# How to evaluate a call in a data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

In one package I'm working on, I'm bumping into a problem that looks simple - but I can't figure it out:

A subfunction is given two arguments:

- `obj`, a `data.frame`
- `foo`, a `call`

For example:

```
> head(obj)
  cadmium copper lead zinc  elev
1    11.7     85  299 1022 7.909
2     8.6     81  277 1141 6.983
3     6.5     68  199  640 7.800
4     2.6     81  116  257 7.655
5     2.8     48  117  269 7.480
6     3.0     61  137  281 7.791
> foo
log(cadmium)
> class(foo)
[1] "call"
```

In that example, I want to create a vector `x <- log(obj$cadmium)`. How do I do that? I tried using `with()` but I don't get the expected result:

```
> with(obj, foo)
log(cadmium)
```

`foo` is a call created by the user by specifying a transformation on a column of the data.frame `obj`:

```
my_function(obj, foo = log(cadmium)) { ... }
```

`dput()` of data snippet:

```
obj <- data.frame(
  cadmium = c(11.7, 8.6, 6.5, 2.6, 2.8, 3),
  copper = c(85L, 81L, 68L, 81L, 48L, 61L),
  lead = c(299L, 277L, 199L, 116L, 117L, 137L),
  zinc = c(1022L, 1141L, 640L, 257L, 269L, 281L),
  elev = c(7.909, 6.983, 7.8, 7.655, 7.48, 7.791),
  row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")
)
```

Comment: Your Q is incomplete - you need to show how `foo` was created; I had to guess at something in my answer.

Comment: Valid point. I added some details. Hopefully it is easier to understand now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to evaluate the call, for example using `eval()`:

```
foo <- call("log", quote(cadmium))
with(obj, eval(foo))
```

which gives:

```
> with(obj, eval(foo))
[1] 2.4595888 2.1517622 1.8718022 0.9555114 1.0296194 1.0986123
```

where `obj` is the snippet of data you showed.

`eval()` also has an `envir` argument indicating the environment within which the expression is evaluated. As such you can do what you want without `with()` using `eval()` directly:

```
> eval(foo, envir = obj)
[1] 2.4595888 2.1517622 1.8718022 0.9555114 1.0296194 1.0986123
```

Comment: You really love to use with! I'd recommending reading `with.default` so you can do the operations directly.

Comment: @hadley You mean using `eval(substitute(foo), obj, enclos = parent.frame())` directly? Any motivation for that?

Comment: @hadley to be fair, the `with()` here was the usage the OP requested, which I then simplified to using `eval()` directly. But yes, I do like `with()`, though not for things like this...

Comment: Pierre Yes, `foo` is an argument to your function so doing what `with()` is doing will save you an extra function call. You shouldn't need to specify `enclose`.

Answer (score 4):

Something like

```
z <- data.frame(a1=1:5,b1=LETTERS[1:5],c1=letters[1:5])
foo <- quote(log(a1))
eval(foo,envir=z)
```

but beware: once you start using `eval` you are descending into the lower depths of R.  I still don't fully understand the distinctions among calling frames, enclosing frames, etc. etc. ...

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you defined a function properly:

```
> foo <- function(x) log(x)
> class(foo)
[1] "function"
```

Then do:

```
x <- foo(obj$cadmium)
```

Or:

```
x <- foo(obj[["cadmium"]])
```

Or:

```
x <- with(obj, foo(cadmium)
```

Comment: Sorry, I might have given too few details. The function I'm working on can accept calls. Eg if I want to plot the logarithm of the cadmium values accessed from the `cadmium` column of a `obj` data.frame, I want the user to be able to use the following synthax (inspired from `ggplot2`): `my_function(obj, colours = log(cadmium)`.